# Find and Replace Incrementally Across Multiple Files - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, replace, find, increment

I apologize in advance if this belongs in SuperUser, I always have a hard time discerning whether these scripting in bash questions are better placed here or there. Currently I know how to find and replace strings in multiple files, and how to find and replace strings within a single file incrementally from searching for a solution to this issue, but how to combine them eludes me.

**Here's the explanation:**

- I have a few hundred files, each in sets of two: a data file (.data), and a message file (data.ms).
- These files are linked via a key value unique to each set of two that looks like: **ab.cdefghi**

**Here's what I want to do:**

- Step through each .data file and do the following:
- Find:

  ```
  MessageKey ab.cdefghi
  ```
- Replace:

  ```
  MessageKey xx.aaa0001
  MessageKey xx.aaa0002
  ...
  MessageKey xx.aaa0010
  etc.
  ```

  Incrementing by 1 every time I get to a new file.

**Clarifications:**

- For reference, there is only one instance of "MessageKey" in every file.
- The paired files have the same name, only their extensions differ, so I could simply step through all .data files and then all .data.ms files and use whatever incremental solution on both and they'd match fine, don't need anything too fancy to edit two files in tandem or anything.
- For all intents and purposes whatever currently appears on the line after each MessageKey is garbage and I am completely throwing it out and replacing it with xx.aaa####
- String length does matter, so I need xx.aa0009, xx.aaa0010 not xx.aa0009, xx.aa00010
- I'm using cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by creating a mapping from old key to new and dumping that into a temp file.

```
grep MessageKey *.data \
  | sort -u \
  | awk '{ printf("%s:xx.aaa%04d\n", $1, ++i); }' \
  > /tmp/key_mapping
```

From there I would confirm that the file looks right before I applied the mapping using sed to the files.

```
cat /tmp/key_mapping \
  | while read old new; do
      sed -i -e "s:MessageKey $old:MessageKey $new:" * \
    done
```

This will probably work for you, but it's neither elegant or efficient.  This is how I would do it if I were only going to run it once.  If I were going to run this regularly and efficiency mattered, I would probably write a quick python script.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm attempting to work with your solution and here's how far I've gotten so far.

I ran this command, slightly modified because these files are inside of various sub-directories:

    find . -iname "*.Data" | grep -R "MessageKey" | sort -u | awk '{ printf("%s:xx.aaa%04d\n", $1, ++i); }' > MessageKey

The output file looks something like this:

Directory/Directory/Filename1.data::xx.aaa0001
Directory/Directory/Filename2.data::xx.aaa0002
...

Comment: I didn't have any luck with the second command because I am assuming based on what I see in the sed command, it's supposed to be looking at a file that looks like this:

ab.cdefg::xx.aaa0001
ab.cdefh::xx.aaa0002
...

Where the old MessageKeys are matched up to the new MessageKeys? I've only just recently started messing around with scripting in bash so unfortunately I'm not intimately familiar with awk or sed. Explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The while loop is reading two variables at a time, so it expects each line of your input file to have a whitespace separated input.  My original thinking was that you would have lines like `ab.cdefghi xx.aaa0001`.  Your approach has changed to use the filename and the new key - but where is the old key?  How will sed know _what_ to replace with the new key?  I think your mapping should have both.  In the sed expression I gave you, it was applying the substitution to _all_ the files.  So _all_ occurrences of `ab.cdefghi` would be replaced with `xx.aaa0001` across all files.

Comment: Hi Carl, sorry for the confusion, I understood what you were trying to do, but not how to reproduce the results. Printing the filename followed by the new key was not intentional, it's just what happened when I modified the command so that I could run it. I'm not intimately familiar with AWK so I'm not sure where I went wrong and why I can't get it to print both the old and new keys. For reference to the command as I ran it, I posted in the above comment. Also, _all_ occurrences is completely fine as each file has a unique key.

Comment: I adjusted the command to `grep -hr "MessageKey" . | sort -u | awk '{ printf("%s:xx.aaa%04d\n", $1, ++i); }'` but the AWK command still seems to be simply replacing the old key instead of printing a new key next to the old key. That's the part I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Well I believe I managed to get the first half of this to work now, I now have a file that looks like where each line looks like `In.Ztvluc1:aa.xxx0105` which I created using `grep -hr "MessageKey" . | sort -u | awk '{ printf("%s:xx.aaa%04d\n", $2, ++i); }' > MessageKey` Turns out the issue was the $1 which needed to be $2 because the line is actually `MessageKey ab.cdefg` when researching the meaning of the $ character in AWK I discovered the problem. I'm still trying to get the SED command to work right with the files I have researching SED, at the moment it simply does nothing.

Comment: I was finally able to get the solution to work with a lot of tweaking, I posted a response to my question myself so people can use it for reference who might have similar troubles with all the tweaks I made to the commands, but I'm accepting your answer as it's how I got to my solution!

Answer (score 0):

@Carl.Anderson got me started on the right track and after a little tweaking, I ended up implementing his solution but with some syntax tweaks.

First of all, this solution only works if all of your files are located in the same directory. I'm sure anyone with even slightly more experience with UNIX than me could modify this to work recursively, but here goes:

**First I ran:**

```
-hr "MessageKey" . | sort -u | awk '{ printf("%s:xx.aaa%04d\n", $2, ++i); }' > MessageKey
```

This command was used to create a find and replace map file called "MessageKey."

The contents of which looked like:

```
In.Rtilyd1:aa.xxx0087
In.Rzueei1:aa.xxx0088
In.Sfricf1:aa.xxx0089
In.Slooac1:aa.xxx0090
etc...
```

**Then I ran:**

```
MessageKey | while IFS=: read old new; do sed -i -e "s/MessageKey $old/MessageKey $new/" *Data ; done
```

I had to use IFS=: (or I could have alternatively find and replaced all : in the map file with a space, but the former seemed easier.

Anyway, in the end this worked! Thanks Carl for pointing me in the right direction.